# how to use html files present in system in contextual help eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin, and it has an extension as:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
      <contexts
            file="contexts.xml"
            plugin="my.plugin.id">
      </contexts>
   </extension>
```

**contexts.xml** has:

```
<contexts>
   <context id="test_context" title="About Contexts">
      <description>This is written by me.</description>
      <topic href="http://www.google.com" label="Search about me" />
   </context>
</contexts>
```

and I am using it as:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(parent, "my.plugin.id.test_context");
```

in topic href how do I use a html file located in system .? :ike it is in C:/test ?
I tried

```
href="C:/test/t.html" label="Search about me"/>
```

I also tried with \ instead of / in href, sytill no use. It seemed like it took only html files within workspace! any workaround?

Comment: A `file` URL might work - `file:///c:/test/t.html`

Comment: @greg-449 no it did not work. I made a intermediate html file in project and from that I called the external html file using eclipse help js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a intermediate html file in project and from that I called the external html file using eclipse help javascript file.